# Stackoverflow: multiprocessing with extra IF condition?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My code is

```
from some_module import foo, tasks, condition
import multiprocessing

def parallel():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(foo, tasks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__' and condition:
    parallel()
```

My question is, what is the flow of this code? As I understand it, first time, it goes into the if-block, then goes into parallel, where it creates a pool, and once I call `.map`, it creates new child processes, and these child processes will … do what, exactly? Will they run the entire script? I know that means it won't go into the if-block, but if that's the case, how the hell does it know what to do? It's only the if-block which tells it to run a function...

Comment: did you miss mentioning the if block in your code snippet?

Comment: No? It just runs the parallel. I can see my title is confusing.